# Firefox incorrectly calculates width of parent

Tags: css, firefox

I have a simple 2-cell grid which is wrapped into an `a` element with `display: inline-block` to shrink its width based on its content. It works as expected in IE and chrome but part of the right cell is hidden in Firefox. It seems like firefox grabs width of the wider cell and applies it to their parent while IE and chrome combine width of both cells, which is what I would like to achieve crossbrowser.

[What it looks like in different browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFWUO.png)

**Demo** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/749x1tud/2/)

**Please note** that adding `float: left` to the 2nd cell or removing `overflow: hidden` doesn't work for me because the grid is like a standalone component and if it's not wrapped into the a element, width of the 1st cell should be based on its content while the 2nd cell should fill the remaining space and their content shouldn't overflow.

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: Your reasoning for why adding/removing certain properties won’t work for you seems rather bogus. Formating something differently based on whether it is a child/descendant of an `a` element, can easily be done using the appropriate selectors.

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry for not being clear but I'm not in control of the outermost element nor its class, therefore I can't specify anything like `.embedded-resources .b-2 {float: left}`. Also the outermost element isn't necessarily an `a` element, it can be any element with `display: inline-block`.